# How can we avoid NOISE SUPRESSION and Echo Cancellation in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, voip

I am using GoogleWebRTC to achieve VOIP calls.. While talk, it's keep on creating some noise suppression and echo cancellation in almost all network modes.. Could you please anyone help me with this?

```
pod 'GoogleWebRTC'
```

**Android Platform used following stuff to avoid Noise Suppression**

```
WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAcousticEchoCanceler(true);
WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAutomaticGainControl(true);
WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedNoiseSuppressor(true);
```

**For iOS Platform**

Please suggest me, what to use to avoid Noise Suppression and Echo Cancellation

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the `RTCMediaConstraints` and the `RTCConfiguration` you are using when you initialize your `RTCPeerConnection` ?

Answer (score 0):

A good idea could be to take a look at your `AVAudioSession` notifications after the stream is established.

In the object that retains the stream add an observer for the `routeChangeNotification`

```
//inside an object that is retained during your stream

init() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, using: routeChange)
}

private func routeChange(_ n: Notification) {
    do {
         try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .videoChat, options: [.mixWithOthers, .defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth, .allowAirPlay])
     } catch {
       print(error)
     }
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification, object: nil)
}
```

setting your `AVAudioSession`s category to `playAndRecord` in the obove options is what you want for a video chat.